# Why this component doesn't works?

Tags: android, react-native, mobile

I've started to learn react-native and I'm trying to create a component but, when I see the code an error is appearing. Does someone know why this component is not working?

[Image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIWDc.png)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `Component` from the already imported React class, like this : `Component` for `React.Component`

Answer (score 0):

You need to import Component from 'react' package like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
```

or, you can use Component from the already imported React class, like this

```
   class MeuComponente extends React.Component {
     // your code here
   }
```

both solutions are equivalent